# wm_nccalcsize, win7 aero and opengl - creating custom window frame

Tags: winapi, opengl, borderless

Is it possible to use the trick with overriding wm_nccalcsize to draw over entire window area with opengl?

I need to keep all aero features for windows (win 7 in this case), so i use (WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_THICKFRAME) styles

It works fine for maximized mode, I can leave the border outside the screen by adjusting the Lparam.

But a regular window still has 8px borders around it, even though they are supposedly part of client rect (which I checked with GetClientRect()

[Image: dark-grey border is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvzAS.png)

And this is all done before I init opengl context. So I dont know what's happening. Or if this even possible. Am I supposed to just create borderless and re-implement all aero features? (no way I'm doing that)

upd 2:
If I draw a rect with GDI right before I init Opengl context this is what i get:
[a nice (0,0,200,200) rect, starting in the nonclient area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG5Mc.png)
So it is opengl context issue. I saw in msdn docs, that opengl draws only in client area. And it still does that, ignoring that I extended the client rect to whole window. siiiigh.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to combine Aero with OpenGL is to set the window client area using the DWM API to zero. This allows you to draw to the whole window (including titlebar) using OpenGL. I have this test program to tinker with it as part of my wglarb wrapper:

https://github.com/datenwolf/wglarb/blob/master/test/layered.c

You may also be interested in my dwm_load wrapper, which allows to you call DWM functions without rigidly linking your program against DWM (which makes it incompatible with older Windows versions; you wouldn't believe how often I still get "must run on WinXP" as a feature requirement) https://github.com/datenwolf/dwm_load

Comment: cool, I'll check out the loader. might want to support xp too.

Comment: I remember trying stuff with margins a year ago or so. Gave up too back then (as I'm about to now). 

There's still border-width offset before my opengl content. Even though the non-client area is clearly being completely overdrawn.
It even draws over bottom and right sides... sigh (see upd. in post)

Thanks anyway, I'll dig around some more. (oh, I also used my own opengl init to build your test thing, hope it's not causing this, because you used ARB functions to create context)

Comment: @StasL: OpenGL contexts are mostly opaque, so it doesn't really matter where the entry points come from. Loaders like GLEW, GLee, glLoadGen and so on happily coexist in a single program.